# Azure functions blob trigger across resource groups

Tags: azure-functions

I am working on a Python based Azure Function on ResourceGroup1. I want the function to be triggered as soon as a new blob is created within the container of the StorageAccount of ResourceGroup2. I'm not sure how to set the connection string or path. Right now I'm trying:

```
{
  "scriptFile": "__init__.py",
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myblob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "container_name/test.txt",
      "connection": "ResourceGroup2/StorageAccount_name"
    }
  ]
}
```

This, however, does not work...

Comment: connection=> The name of an app setting that contains the Storage connection string to use for this binding. If the app setting name begins with "AzureWebJobs", you can specify only the remainder of the name here. For example, if you set connection to "MyStorage", the Functions runtime looks for an app setting that is named "AzureWebJobsMyStorage." If you leave connection empty, the Functions runtime uses the default Storage connection string in the app setting that is named AzureWebJobsStorage.

The connection string must be for a general-purpose storage account, not a Blob storage account.

Comment: Your connection is wrong.

Comment: Hi, can you us use it now?

Comment: Hi, I updated the connection string in the applications as you suggested and included it into the function.json. Thanks for that! Unfortunately it's still not getting a trigger signal when I upload a .txt to the specified container. But it worked fine using an event grid trigger

Comment: Seems to work now, It needs some time to show up in the logs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should get the connection string from this place:

[image]

If you are develop on azure, your function.json should be like this:

```
{
  "bindings": [
    {
      "name": "myBlob",
      "type": "blobTrigger",
      "direction": "in",
      "path": "samples-workitems/{name}",
      "connection": "TheConnectionString"
    }
  ]
}
```

You should add the TheConnectionString in this place:

[image]

If you develop on local, add the string in this place:

**local.settings.json:**

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "xxxxxx"
  }
}
```